# Python TypeError: an integer is required while working with Sockets on the client side

Tags: python, sqlite, sockets

can some one help please, i am running my code connecting the client to the server that connects to a database and when i am sending the info from the client to the server with the ID as an int, an error would appear saying: TypeError: must be string or buffer, not int.
And when changing the ID into a string at the server side, an error would appear saying: TypeError: an integer is required

Please help me because i got confused...

#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import socket
import sqlite3 as lite

global s
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

class client:

```
#functions on the client side only send the data to the server side (their only job)
def login(ID, password):
    try:
        s.send(self, ID)
        s.send(password)
    except IOError:
           print "Error! Cannot execute statement."

def signup(self, ID, Name, Email, Password):
    try:
        s.send(ID, Name)
        s.send(Email, Password)
    except IOError:
           print "Error! Cannot execute statement."

def addContact(self, ID, name, email):
    try:
        s.send(ID, name)
        s.send(email)
    except IOError:
        print "Error! Cannot execute statement."
```

class main:
    # create a socket object
    c = client()
    Register = "Register"
    Login = "Login"

```
# get local machine name
host = socket.gethostname()

port = 9999

# connection to hostname on the port.
s.connect((host, port))

Message = input("Login if you are a user. If you are new, register here so you could play checkers! \t")
if Message == Login:
    ID = input("ID \t")
    password = input("Password \t")
    c.login(ID, password)

elif Message == Register:
    ID = input("ID \t")
    Name = input("Name \t")
    Email = input("Email \t")
    Password = input("Password \t")
    c.signup(ID, Name, Email, Password)

elif Message == add:
    ID = input("ID \t")
    Name = input("Name \t")
    Email = input("Email \t")
    c.addContact(ID, name, email)
else:
    exit()


# Receive no more than 1024 bytes
data = s.recv(1024)

s.close()

print("The time got from the server is %s" % data.decode('ascii'))
```

Comment: We need the full traceback and an explanation of what you are trying to do.  If possible, it would be really nice if you could create a [mcve].

Comment: OK, look where the `TypeError` message appears.  Above that message, you'll see some text that starts with `Traceback (most recent call last):` and then has several lines of the form `File <something>, line <some number>, in <something else>`.  I need all of that information.

Comment: it is in line 22 in signup: s.send(ID, Name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call `s.send()` like this:

```
s.send(ID, Name)
s.send(Email, Password)
```

When you call that method with two arguments, the second argument [is supposed to be an integer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send).  Specifically, it is supposed to be the bitwise OR of zero or more "flag values"; a list can be found [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/send) (scroll down a bit).  Zero means no flags and is probably what you want for most simple cases.  The argument defaults to zero if you do not pass it at all.  For this case, I imagine you want to write four separate calls to `send()`, like this:

```
s.send(ID)
s.send(Name)
s.send(Email)
s.send(Password)
```

Please also bear in mind that TCP is a "stream-oriented" protocol (`SOCK_STREAM`), meaning the above is exactly the same as this:

```
everything = ''.join([ID, Name, Email, Password])
# Equivalent to but faster than: everything = ID + Name + Email + Password
s.send(everything)
```